Синонимизировать [push] с [git-push]
Метка push используется для двух разных понятий:

Команда git push в Git.
Метод массивов в javascript.

Это - совершенно разные вещи. Нужно убрать [push] со вопросов про массивы, и синонимизировать её с [git-push].

почему ты думаешь, что ее нужно синонимизировать именно с [tag:git-push] ?

А с чем еще????

В принципе с чем угодно, например [tag:push-уведомления]

Если у метки 3 и больше совершенно разных значений, лучше уж жечь ее, а не выбирать какое-то одно для синонима.

Да, по моему эту метку надо полностью сжечь и ни с чем не синонимизировать (так будет только хуже).
